# MySQL case statements with count function

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables

1. restaurants
2. dishes

**restaurants(id,name,address)**

**dishes(id,name,restaurantId,professionalImage)**

I need to output all the restaurants with `id`, `name`, `address` and another field called `isAllPhotosFilled`

Condition is

```
if (count(dishes.professionalImage is null or dishes.professionalImage ='') == 0)
{
   isAllPhotosFilled = true
}
else{
   isAllPhotosFilled = false
}
```

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    restaurants.name AS name,
    restaurants.id AS id,
    restaurants.address AS address,
    CASE
        WHEN
            COUNT(dishes.professionalImage IS NULL
                OR dishes.professionalImage = '') = 0
        THEN
            TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END AS isAllPhotosFilled
FROM
    eat_me.restaurants
        LEFT JOIN
    dishes ON restaurants.id = dishes.restaurantId
GROUP BY name , id , address
```

What's wrong with this query?

Comment: What issue you are getting? Also as id ane name columns are there in both table it should give you ambiguous column name error.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue in applying CASE/WHEN and COUNT. Please check the below code-

```
SELECT R.id, 
       R.name, 
       R.address,
       CASE
           WHEN SUM(CASE
                        WHEN D.professionalImage IS NULL
                             OR D.professionalImage = ''
                        THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END) = 0
           THEN 'True'
           ELSE 'False'
       END AS isAllPhotosFilled
       -- You can change the True/False selection oppositely if I am wrong
FROM restaurants R
     LEFT JOIN dishes D ON R.id = D.restaurantId
GROUP BY R.id, 
         R.name, 
         R.address;
```